# XML schema for electric circuits

Tags: layout, circuit-analysis

Is there any XML schema to describe electric/electronic circuits? I am thinking of something like a netlist, but using XML markup.

Comment: It should be possible to script a translation from a normal netlist format into a simple XML schema. But ... why?

Comment: @BrianDrummond: I thought so. `:)` But has anybody actually done it? I'm interested, because I'd like to generate a schematic in some vector graphic format e.g. `SVG`(which is XML at its heart...).

Comment: Doesn't Kicad use XML?

Comment: @jippie: Kicad can create SVG files, so in a way, yes.

Comment: I guess having a look to the files produced by TinyCAD would help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of Version 6, the Eagle layout and routing program has been using XML for all of its files, including schematics and board layouts.  You can download a [freeware version here,](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/download-eagle/freeware/?language=en) generate a schematic and look at the corresponding .sch file, which will be in XML.

Prior to using XML, their files were all in a proprietary binary format.  Now it is possible for third parties to develop tools & utilities that can read and manipulate Eagles files, providing added value.

Note that even a tiny schematic may generate a ton of XML; I drew a simply RC circuit and the files was 5800 lines long.  The reason for this appears to be that when you specify a part out of a library, Eagle copies the entire library into the schematic file; this has the advantage that you can give the schematic to someone else that may not have the same library, and they can render it properly.

Once the libraries have been accounted for, the description of the circuit itself does not take all that much space; I have a 13-page schematic, several orders of magnitude more complicated than my simple RC test circuit, and the larger file (25K lines) is only about four times as big as the small one, or about 2K lines per page.

Answer (score 1):

Hold off for a while in case anyone knows different; but I have never seen such a format. The Electronics industry had its own common schema (EDIF) from the 1970s, which looked LISP-like for easy parsing, rather than HTML-like for ... I dunno, fashion?

But even so, netlists are frequently expressed in much simpler ad-hoc formats.

You could adopt a schema based on SVG and convert netlists to it : this should be relatively easy.

However if your intent is to use SVG tools to plot or render netlists in some graphic form, remember that netlists merely list entities and interconnections, saying nothing about spatial layout. So you will face "interesting" problems in the area of automatically laying out the blocks and interconnections. I have never seen this done really well. If that is your goal, good luck!

Comment: You could use graphviz (http://www.graphviz.org/) to go from netlist to SVG.  But an XML format is neither necessary or helpful.

Comment: @markrages : I tend to agree with you on the necessity. Eagle is an interesting proof of existence of such a schema; but going from schematic to netlist is a much easier problem than netlist to (viewable netlist, = schematic)